# Loop thru selected folder and subfolders and split powerpoint presentations into individual slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to write code that:

1. Prompts the user for a source folder
2. Prompts if to use the source folder name or the source filename as the destination name
3. Creates a "_ done folder" in each source folder or subfolder
4. loops through all the *.PPT and *.PPTX files in the source folder
5. saves each slide as an individual *.pptx file

I've written the following code but am getting an error on the third to last line when the code should move to the next subfolder (the code is `subfolderName = Dir`):

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim sourceFolder As String
    Dim sequentialOption As Integer
    
    ' Prompt the user for the source folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Source Folder"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sourceFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub ' User cancelled the selection
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Prompt the user for the sequential option
    sequentialOption = MsgBox("Apply sequential number to source filename? (Click Yes for source filename, No for source foldername)", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    
    ' Create the "_done" folder in the destination parent folder
    Dim destinationParentFolder As String
    destinationParentFolder = Left(sourceFolder, InStrRev(sourceFolder, "\") - 1) & "\_done"
    
    ' Create the "_done" folder if it doesn't exist
    If Dir(destinationParentFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir destinationParentFolder
        MsgBox "_done folder created successfully!"
    End If
    
    ' Process the slides in the source folder and its subfolders
    ProcessFolder sourceFolder, destinationParentFolder, sequentialOption
    
    MsgBox "Slides processed successfully!"
    
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolder(ByVal sourceFolder As String, ByVal destinationParentFolder As String, ByVal sequentialOption As Integer)
    Dim processedFolder As String
    Dim slideCount As Long
    Dim slideIndex As Long
    Dim slide As Slide
    Dim sourceFileName As String
    Dim destinationFileName As String
    
    ' Loop through all files in the source folder
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(sourceFolder & "\*.ppt*")
    
    Do While fileName <> ""
        ' Check if it is a file
        If (GetAttr(sourceFolder & "\" & fileName) And vbDirectory) = 0 Then
            ' Open each PowerPoint file
            Dim presentation As Object
            Set presentation = Presentations.Open(sourceFolder & "\" & fileName)
            
            ' Save each slide as a separate file in the destination folder
            slideCount = presentation.Slides.Count
            slideIndex = 1
            
            For Each slide In presentation.Slides
                If sequentialOption = vbYes Then
                    destinationFileName = destinationParentFolder & "\" & _
                                          Left(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, ".") - 1) & " - Slide " & slideIndex & ".pptx"
                Else
                    destinationFileName = destinationParentFolder & "\" & _
                                          Left(sourceFolder, InStrRev(sourceFolder, "\") - 1) & " - Slide " & slideIndex & ".pptx"
                End If
                
                slide.Export destinationFileName, "PPTX"
                
                slideIndex = slideIndex + 1
            Next slide
            
            ' Close the source file
            presentation.Close
        End If
        
        ' Move to the next file
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Process the subfolders
    Dim subfolderName As String
    subfolderName = Dir(sourceFolder & "\*", vbDirectory)
    
    Do While subfolderName <> ""
        ' Ignore the current folder and parent folder entries
        If subfolderName <> "." And subfolderName <> ".." Then
            ' Check if it is a subfolder
            If (GetAttr(sourceFolder & "\" & subfolderName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                ' Process the subfolder recursively
                ProcessFolder sourceFolder & "\" & subfolderName, destinationParentFolder, sequentialOption
            End If
        End If
        
        ' Move to the next subfolder
        subfolderName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code cannot work because you recursively call `ProcessFolder`, starting a new `Dir`-Loop and therefore destroying the Loop of the "higher" level (there can be only one `Dir`-Loop open at a time). For traversing folder structures recursively, use the `FileSystemObject`. Tons of examples here on SO and elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: @MigueldelasNieves So, solved yet?